# iPhone photo recovery

Tags: icloud, photo-stream

I transferred my photos to the stream and they were all there, I went back recently and noticed a section was deleted, is there any way possible for me to recover those photos?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if they are in the recently deleted album.